# In Durandal how can you get a handle to the active VM in debug or developer tool console?

Tags: debugging, durandal

Building an app with Duranrdal for the first time and I'd like to be able to use the chrome developer tools console to inspect values of my view models on various pages as they are loaded.

the problem is there is no window.Durandal or window.MainApp that i can see.  I could do this in main.js define function:

```
window.myApp = app;
```

but that seems like a hack, and it doesn't really get me a handle to the current viewmodel.  I thought about just doing similar code in the router, but this is also really ugly.

Is my app & current VM accessable in some clearner way? perhaps the require.js when it loads the modules puts that reference on the dom somewhere? I suppose if i can get a handle to the router i'd be ok.

I'm also interested in getting a handle to the VM backing a modal dialog..not sure if you can get to that off the router or some other piece.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome developer tools you can put break points in your viewmodels and step through the code.  Also, durandal logs your viewmodel objects that have been composed to the console.log so you can see the state at which they were bound to a view.

Here is another way which is just making use of the mechanics of requirejs to get a reference to your viewmodel object programmatically.  Just type something like this into your chrome console:

```
require(['durandal/pluggins/router','yourViewModel'], function (router, vm) {
    // here you can do whatever you want now to your router or vm.
    vm.someproperty('changed');
    router.activateRoute('page2');
});
```

You can even make a global reference to the objects you want to change by doing this in the console:

```
require(['durandal/pluggins/router','yourViewModel'], function (router, vm) {
    window.TestVM = vm;
    window.router = router;
});
```

Then you can access those objects like so:

```
TestVM.someproperty('changed');
router.activateRoute('page2');
```

Comment: don't want logs, and yes i can do breakpoints, but i don't want the code to be paused.  I like to change the value of observables and see how the view changes...can't do that with a breakpoint...  Your suggestion about bringin in the requirements makes sense for the router, but what if the viewmodel isn't a singleton?

Comment: bring down the vm that has a reference to the instance of the other vm.  As long as the VM in reference is not totally encapsulated.. it can be done.

Comment: how would i get a handle to the VM of a dialog from a dialog.Show() call?

Comment: in the VM that is calling dialog.Show() are you passing in a string as an argument to the show property? or are you passing in the actual amd module? I think your just going to have change ur code to expose certain objects. Otherwise the objects your trying to access might be fully encapsulated.

Comment: passing just a string

Comment: well if you acquire the amd module first, possibly using durandal's system.acquire method, then you will have reference to the amd module.  Because if your passing a string then you wont be able to get reference to that module instance because it is encapsulated w/in the dialog module.

Answer (score 1):

In the console just enter:

```
viewmodel = require('viewmodels/myviewmodel')
```

Comment: that was the other suggestion, but what if you view model isn't a singleton?

Comment: I am using Opera 36 that is based in same  googles's chrome engine. Something i just notice is that in debug mode ( system.debug(true) in main.js) at least in Durandal version 2.1, every activated model is output in the console, i just have to right click in the object and select the option "Store as global variable", this creates a global variable named "temp1", i don't known if this works the same with non singletons, but is very handy.